# Why doesn't a comment directed to me show in my inbox nor under responses?

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies, global-inbox

(A happy new year, everyone)

Glossing over past comments, I found [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728811/prolog-sum-up-positioned-elem-in-list/2734458#comment49544994_2734458) directed to me that I did not remember at all. Also my inbox and responses folder does not contain that message:

[image: Nothing at 2015-06-09 after 23:00]

So, why did/does this message not show in my inbox?

Comment: Have you written something under that answer prior sharkys comment? If not, then adding `@false` won't do anything.

Comment: The message is for the original comment writer, too :)

Comment: (To answer this question now, as all other comments are gone) No I have not written anything, nor have I (downvoted) it.

Answer (score 9):

You were not eligible for an @-mention that triggers an inbox notification because you had not interacted with the post via edit or (non-deleted) comment.

One cannot just @-ping arbitrary users; for the exact rules see [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: So there is no feedback that a @name will not trigger a message, yes?

Comment: That is correct. @false